# task bar flickering after upgrading to ubuntu 22.04

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, system-monitor

After upgrading my Ubuntu version to 22.04 I've noticed that the system monitor icon on the task bar (located in the upper right corner by default) glitches / flickers unnaturally. Doesn't seem to influence the functioning of it, but is quite annoying.
I've attached a gif to present the issue.

Can anybody suggest on how to fix this?

[image: example]